# Espaço branco indesejado entre imagem e borda

Tags: html, css

Toda vez q eu coloco a borda ele fica com esse problema, o engraçado é q esta funcionando de boa em outros projetos (tentei colocar a borda direto no figure.foto-legenda img, funcionou mas para criar os efeitos ficou bem zoado e antes não estava assim.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Testando </title>

  <style>

  figure.foto-legenda {
   border: 3px solid black;
   position: relative;

   }

  figure.foto-legenda img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
  }

  figure.foto-legenda figcaption {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px
  }

  </style>
 </head>
 <body>

 <h1>The Simpsons</h1>
  <figure class="foto-legenda">
   <img src="imagens/homer.jpg"/>
    <figcaption>
     <h1> Homer Simpson </h1>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A própria imagem não tem esse espaço em branco? Dai é melhor remover cortando com algum editor de imagens

Comment: Não e já testei com varias imagens.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução alternativa para o seu problema é adicionar width e height em figure.foto-legenda:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Testando </title>

  <style>

  figure.foto-legenda {
   border: 3px solid black;
   position: relative;
                        width: 800px;
                        height: 600px;

   }

  figure.foto-legenda img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
  }

  figure.foto-legenda figcaption {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px
  }

  </style>
 </head>
 <body>

 <h1>The Simpsons</h1>
  <figure class="foto-legenda">
   <img src="https://www.tricurioso.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/fatos-curiosos-sobre-o-homer-simpson-667x400.jpg"/>
    <figcaption>
     <h1> Homer Simpson </h1>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

**tente isso aqui**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Testando </title>

        <style>

        figure.foto-legenda {
            border: 3px solid black;
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
        }

        figure.foto-legenda img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        figure.foto-legenda figcaption {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px
        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>The Simpsons</h1>
        <figure class="foto-legenda">
            <img src="https://cdn-ofuxico.akamaized.net/img/upload/noticias/2018/08/22/what-homer-simpson-taught-us-about-doughnuts_327781_36.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>
                    <h1> Homer Simpson </h1>
                </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pra vc ver q loucura, eu fiz o codigo denovo do mesmo jeito e funcionou. O meu codigo funcionou pra vc?

Comment: kkkkkkk normal, as vezes se passamos mesmo, o cansaço kkkkk, mas depois adicione o display, pra não acontecer mais isso. kkkkk

Comment: Mas oq esse display faz?

Comment: o display especifica o comportamento de exibição (o tipo de caixa de renderização) de um elemento.